# Always traverse the Business Layer to get to the Data Layer?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have set up my VS Solution with the common layers in separate projects: Presentation, Business, Entities, and Data Access Layers. I have this static class `AppSettings` in the DAL which i want to call its `Load()` method at `Application_Start` in the Globla.asax.cs. It basically loads up my application settings from the web.config.

My question is: Should i be making a business logic class to access it from my Presentation Layer or can i access my AppSettings directly from my Presentation Layer to the DataAccess Layer (ignoring the Business Layer).

If so, does the same go for everything? Must i always go through the business layer to get to the Data Layer?

```
public static class AppSettings
{
    public static int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public static string ServiceEndpoint { get; set; }
    public static string ServiceCode { get; set; }
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public static void Load()
    {
        //Connection String
        AppSettings.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["USpace"].ConnectionString;

        //Applicatin Settings
        AppSettings.ApplicationID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppID"]);
        AppSettings.ServiceEndpoint = (string)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceEndpoint"];
        AppSettings.ServiceCode = (string)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceCode"];
    }
}
```

If i must go through the business logic Layer the BLL's class will look like this?:

```
public static class BLLAppSettings
{
    public static int ApplicationID
    {
        get
        {
            AppSettings.ApplicationID
        }
    }
 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your focus is Design Patterns, then by all means, have fun pounding those square pegs in the little round holes.

If your focus is on Application Design, then you focus on the Design Patterns that make sense for your Application, and even for individual parts of your Application.

Knowing the patterns is knowledge.  Knowing when, and when not, to use them is wisdom...

It's one man's oppinion, but I hope it helps...

Comment: It does help thanks (+1) are you saying i might not need that business class for accessing the appSettings, just call the DAL directly?

Comment: a business layer is there to provide a place to consistently apply business rules to your data.  if there are no business rules for an entity, then why use a business layer?  layers of extra code that does nothing but supply a warm fuzzy "i followed the pattern" feeling are, to me, a waste...

Comment: The 'Onion' architecture described [here](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) helped get me over my desire to strictly follow the top-down layered architecture.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend always going through the business logic layer to access the data layer, so that all of the safeguards built into the business logic layer are in play.  Would you want the data layer to be used without the business layer?

Answer (score 1):

Ayende recently posted a few articles against this practice (I understood it like that) :

http://ayende.com/blog/153061/northwind-starter-kit-review-it-is-all-about-the-services

And I agree with him : you have to ask your self "what is the purpose of this layer" and if you can't answer then you can't remove this layer and keep your software simple.

So if you have no business operation when you get your data then deal directly with your data layer !

Comment: Interesting, it think you strengthen ShaneBlake's point. (+1)

Comment: I'm definitely an advocate of keeping it simple but I'm also a big proponent of adding enough abstraction up front to keep your options open and your code flexible.  It is definitely a balance but a little abstraction can go a long way.

Comment: @dblood : let's say you now want to email someone when you insert a product. So you'll had your email sending code in your service. You're happy and you think it's easy. BUT what if in some case you don't want to send this mail ? When you have this kind of interrogation that means you broke the SRP principle : you changed your class responsibility ! So that's a layer that could lead you to a lot of pain (like your client receive 10 000 the first night of your patch because you forgot about this batch running every night that uses your service layer).

Comment: @remi - I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying not to use any abstractions?

Comment: @dblood - I'm saying to use abstraction but for a reason, and "I'm might find one later" is not a reason it's the beginning of an over engineered architecture .

Comment: The reason I'm advocating abstraction here is to decouple the BLL and DAL given in the question from Presentation Layer's AppSettings class. Adding abstraction to avoid coupling is perfectly valid and good design.

Comment: @dblood, how is he avoiding coupling with a static class ? If it's solution would implement some kind of adapter pattern I'd agree with you but here there is definitely coupling.

Comment: @remi, My answer does not advocate for a static class but a specific, concrete settings class defined, ideally, with an interface within the application layer. Then the particular app layer is decoupled from the presentation layer static class used in this case. The particular concrete instance class can implement the static AppSettings class or some other mechanism and the other layers are not coupled to an implementation. I'm adding 3 words to  my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in the application's config file (web.config) you don't need to "go through" anything besides `System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`

Comment: You're right since [web.config is already cached](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/01/15/web-config-is-cached.aspx). But Is it okay to be accessing the Sys.Config.App...from all layers?

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you are coupled to web.config. That's can ok sometimes but what if you want to use your BLL in another app that only reads settings from a database?  You have to refactor.  By adding a little bit of abstraction up front, when you have to refactor away from ConfigurationManager your job will be much easier.

Comment: i think it's unnecessary extra work upfront.  it would be easy enough to refactor that when the need presents itself.

Comment: @Jason - You said specifially, what I was trying to say generally. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should start out by keeping it simple but within reason. General principles of software engineering should be your guide when designing your application.  In this case, my immediate thought is that by having one global AppSettings class then you will be coupling your business and data access layer to that class. That may seem reasonable now but what about when you have 50 different settings and only 20 of them apply to the data access layer?  What if, down the road, your business layer has to load the settings from a different source than the DAL? On top of that, in your current design your coupling both layers to global singleton. That is typically not a good idea.

Even in smaller apps I would advocate for having different settings objects defined for each layer.  In my design, it would be similar to your BLLAppSettings. It would encapsulate the source of the settings, in this case your global AppSettings class. However, where my design would differ is that BLLAppSettings would be a concrete instance of an Interface defined in the BLL layer that must be given to the BLL layer via Constructor, Factory, or Dependency Injection. A similar class, DALAppSettings would be necessary in my recommended design.

In this way, your BLL and DAL are not coupled to the global AppSettings defined in the Presentation Layer.  The implementation details of BLLAppSettings and DALAppSettings can vary independently when necessary, but for the time being can remain internally tied to your global AppSettings class.

Comment: Interesting, never thought of that (different setting classes for different layers). Good point (+1)